Using a State property to create a view in a sheet
I am trying to create a view in SwiftUI where by clicking on a button, a sheet is presented. A simplified version of the code looks like this:
struct ExampleView: View {
    @State private var selectedIndex: Int = -1
    @State private var showSheet: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        Text("Tap me!")
            .onTapGesture {
                selectedIndex = 2
                showSheet = true
            }.sheet(isPresented:$showSheet){
                VStack {
                    Text("Selected Index: \(selectedIndex)")
                }
                .onAppear {
                    print("Sheet appeared: selectedIndex = \(selectedIndex)")
                }
            }
    }
}

When I tap on the button, a view is presented with SelectedIndex: -1; however, in the print statement, the correct value appears(Sheet appeared: selectedIndex = 2).
What I would like is for the correct value (2) to be passed when creating the view being presented -- how can I achieve that?

use sheet(item)

what is item? Can you give a bit more details please?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:) in your case the item would be the index so just make the state optional and initialize with nil instead of -1

Thanks a lot, I am getting closer now. It still complains that Instance method 'sheet(item:onDismiss:content:)' requires that 'Int' conform to 'Identifiable' so I maybe need to wrap my Int in a struct?

wrapping in a structure is best if you are truly using int but you can also create an Int extension and make the id a computed property that uses self

Thanks a lot. If you just made that into an answer I could accept it?

You can write it if you want or just delete the question. This same question comes up every couple of days on SO in different contexts
